# Enabling SMTP ports on VCAP

Tags: cloud-foundry

I want to be able to send emails from my applications deployed on VCAP to email providers supporting SMTP. Is there a way to configure VCAP to make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no restriction on outbound communication from Cloud Foundry, you should be able to connect from your applications to any mail service you like.